# What is the format for Query parameters in cache policy for cloudfront

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront, query-string

What is the format for query parameters in the cache policy form of Cloudfront/AWS to allow cache busting. I want to have a parameter with any number.

image.jpg?5(any number here) OR
image.jpg?v=5(any number here)

[Cache policy form field here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUvsG.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the [name of the query parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/controlling-the-cache-key.html#cache-key-understand-cache-policy-settings). In your case, it's `v`. Make sure to add it with the "Add query string" button. You cannot restrict that only number values can be defined there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, but just adding v creates the same error in the cache policy form.